# Redux Saga - [...effects] has been deprecated in favor of all([...effects]), please update your code

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

```
function* rootSaga() {
    yield all(sagas.map(saga => fork(saga)));
}

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

In the above code `sagas` is an array of generator functions which still work as expected. I am new to redux saga so I may not be providing the relevant information but I have followed many guides which all say the same yet i am still getting the deprecation message of

```
[...effects] has been deprecated in favor of all([...effects]), please update your code
```

I am importing the redux-saga functions via

```
import { all, fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';
```

Is there something I am missing here? Everything works fine but i am getting this deprecation warning.

Comment: have you tried adding your sagas individually to the root saga and debugging that way?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you have *should* work. A `fork` is an effect, and the `all` effect is expecting either an object dictionary or an array of effects. At a lower level, I'm pretty sure this means that the `all` effect is expecting generators in either case. On redux-saga's [beginner tutorial page](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) their root saga is put together like this:

```
function* helloSaga() {
  console.log('Hello Sagas!')
}

function* watchIncrementAsync() {
  yield takeEvery('INCREMENT_ASYNC', incrementAsync)
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    helloSaga(),
    watchIncrementAsync()
  ])
}
```

The thing to note here is that in the root saga array `helloSaga` and `watchIncrementAsync` are executed in place and each return a generator. In your example you're returning a `fork`, but that should essentially be the same thing. My best guess here is something about your map is not actually returning an array of effects.